# Convert seconds to date from Jan 01 1901 in unix/linux

Tags: unix-timestamp

im trying to convert a time stamp in seconds from Jan 01 1901 to the current date.

for example,
time stamp 3465468225 translate to a date in 2010.  does anyone know of a way to do this in unix/linux? thanks.

Comment: What do you want to use to convert it? Perl, c++... etc...

Answer (score 0):

In [R](http://www.r-project.org), it is as simple as this:

```
> as.POSIXct(3465468225, origin="1901-01-01")
[1] "2010-10-25 15:03:45 CDT"  
>
```

This uses appropriate wrappers around C-level calls `gmtime()` / `localtime()` plus time formatting via `strftime()`.

Answer (score 0):

On GNU and POSIX systems you can obtain the date string using seconds since Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) as:

```
$ date --date=@1289495920
Thu Nov 11 12:18:40 EST 2010
```

You should handle the offset since Jan 01 1901 yourself.